# Dependant Field on Netsuite Transaction Form

Tags: sql, netsuite

I currently have a dependant field on Sales Orders that lists the CONTACTS (filtered by CUSTOMER), and then other fields which reference values found on the Contact records.
So selecting a Customer, and then a Contact, will automatically populate the inline fields with the relevant data.

[image]

Now I need a way of showing the OPEN CREDITS (for that customer) on Sales Order forms.

I was thinking that there may be a way similar to the above, where I could either make a dependant list field, and the sales rep would have to select from a list of available credits?

Answer (score 0):

create a simple saved search for the open credit then use the saved search to source the field, make sure have customer(entity) as a filter in the search

Comment: similar issue https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/61574/